# Linux Mint 14 - Segfault in steam.sh (cannot launch steam)

Tags: linux-mint, steam

Here is my output when I try to launch steam:

```
tetra@nick-Inspiron ~ $ steam
Running Steam on linuxmint 14 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1373503443_client)
Gen6+ requires Kernel 3.6 or later.
steam: ../../../../../src/mesa/main/context.c:1499: _mesa_make_current: Assertion `newCtx->Version > 0' failed.
[2013-07-13 21:15:04] Startup - updater built Apr 30 2013 10:04:24
[2013-07-13 21:15:04] Opted in to client beta 'publicbeta' via beta file
/home/tetra/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 704:  4342 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Installing bootstrap /home/tetra/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Running Steam on linuxmint 14 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/tetra/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1373503443_client)
Gen6+ requires Kernel 3.6 or later.
steam: ../../../../../src/mesa/main/context.c:1499: _mesa_make_current: Assertion `newCtx->Version > 0' failed.
[2013-07-13 21:15:05] Startup - updater built Apr 30 2013 10:04:24
[2013-07-13 21:15:05] Opted in to client beta 'publicbeta' via beta file
/home/tetra/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 704:  4430 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
```

I don't understand why I can't launch steam. I've reinstalled the package.

Comment: What graphics card do you have and which driver do you use it with?

Comment: This crash is related to graphic card settings. try to update your graphic card driver. a similar issue was resolved by removing `Xinerama` from `xorg.conf`. You may need to use `gdb` to start steam with 'DEBUGGER=gdb` to help narrow down where the failure is happening

Comment: @Salton where is xorg.conf? also how do I update my graphic card driver?

Comment: @terdon i have an nvida 650M but optirun doesn't work atm so I'm using an integrated intel chip

Comment: `xorg.conf` typically located under `/etc/X11`. You can run `update-pciids` to fetches the current version of the pci.ids file from the primary distribution site and install it but you can ultimately look for graphic card manufacture's website for drive updates.